# Auditd service restart creates auoms.rules file to /etc/audit/rules.d/

Tags: 18.04

Installed `auditd` to my Ubuntu 18.04 but setting rules is causing issues. I want to get rid of `auoms.rules`.

`auoms.rules` (`etc/audit/rules.d/auoms.rules`) file has rules that I don't need and they are merged to `etc/audit/audit.rules` every time Auditd service restarts. If I delete it, it gets re-created and merged again. If I comment the rules, changes will be overwritten and merged.

I have tried instruction here: `/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service` to disable augen rules but that did not work. `auoms.rules` file was created and merged as previously. Also also tried following guide to do the same thing:

1. Move the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/auditd.service` to prevent the old file from calling `augenrules` then from `/etc/systemd/system/auditd.service` remove the comment from `ExecStartPost=-/sbin/auditctl -R /etc/audit/audit.rules` save it
2. clear old rules from `/etc/audit/audit.rules`. Then `systemctl daemon-reload` followed by service `auditd restart`
3. `service auditd status` To show the following below. `Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-07-05 18:49:51 UTC; 1s ago Process: 8377 ExecStartPost=/sbin/auditctl -R /etc/audit/audit.rules (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Everything worked and I was able to `ExecStartPost=/sbin/auditctl -R /etc/audit/audit.rules` when getting status.

However when I ran `auditctl -l` (to see current rules), I noticed that auoms rules are there again...:

```
-w /bin/kmod -p x -k auoms -k kernelmodules <br>
-w /var/log/audit -p wxa -k audittampering -k auoms  
-w /etc/audit -p wxa -k audittampering -k auoms  
-w /etc/passwd -p wxa -k auoms -k usergroup 
-w /etc/group -p wxa -k auoms -k usergroup  
-w /etc/pam.d -p wxa -k auoms -k pam 
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve,execveat -F key=auoms 
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve,execveat -F key=auoms
```

Comment: Anyone? I really can't find solution to this. auoms -rules generate massive amount of logs to SIEM and I really want them removed. Now changes won't survive restart and auoms rules are added to my own rules.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it. Adding audit rules to `etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` with exactly the same conditions as `auoms` rules have, but using `-a never, exit` seems to work. Because of the first rule match principle, the audit.rules file will be processed before the `auoms.rules`.

```
-a never,exit /bin/kmod -p x -k iwantthesegone
-a never,exit /var/log/audit -p wxa -k iwantthesegone
-a never,exit /etc/audit -p x -k iwantthesegone
-a never,exit /etc/pam.d -p x -k iwantthesegone
-a never,exit /etc/passwd -p x -k iwantthesegone
-a never,exit /etc/group -p x -k iwantthesegone
-a never,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve,execveat -F key=iwantthesegone
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem this week. In my case was related with Microsoft.
Maybe you can find more details here: https://github.com/microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux

In fact it generates auoms rule every time you restart auditd.
To solve, I comment lines below on file /etc/opt/microsoft/auoms/rules.d/oms-security-audit.rules

```
...
#-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve,execveat -F key=auoms 
#-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve,execveat -F key=auoms
```

And exec chattr to make file immutable

```
root@host# chattr +i /etc/opt/microsoft/auoms/rules.d/oms-security-audit.rules
```